# Qt-Creator doesn't create a .pro file

Tags: c++, sqlite, qt-creator

[image: No .pro file founded]

I want to connect Qt with Sqlite. Everyone on YouTube says that we need to type QT += core gui sql inside of .pro file, but the problem is that after I created a Qt Widget Application I haven't found the .pro file. Probably the problem is connected with using CMake, but I cannot change to qmake, because our lecturer told us to use CMake in our coursework. I wish the problem is not that hard, and beautiful community is able to help me.

Comment: Qt is the framework Qt-Creator is the IDE. I am pretty sure you are talking about an issue with the IDE

Comment: In your picture the answer is very clear to me the project is using CMake instead of QMake. The `CMake` equivalent of the .pro file is the `CMakeList.txt` file

Comment: Ok, I really appreciate your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Since you created a CMake-based project, the corresponding project file is called `CMakeLists.txt`, not a `.pro` file.

The corresponding command to `QT += sql` for linking against the Qt Sql module, is `find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Sql REQUIRED)` for CMake projects.

See also the [Get Started with CMake](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/cmake-get-started.html) documentation from the Qt documentation.